# Prove the intersection of two compact sets is compact using the Bolzano-Weierstrass condition for compactness.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Criterion for a compactness (Bolzano-Weierstrass condition for compactness I believe):

> A Set S $\in \Bbb R^n$ is compact if every sequence in $S$ has a convergent subsequence to a point in $S$.

Using the statement above, prove that the intersection of two compact sets is compact.

**My attempt at the proof:**

Let compact sets $A$ and $B$ be given. By the criterion above, we know:

- Every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence to a point in $A$.
- Every sequence in $B$ has a convergent subsequence to a point in $B$.

Consider the subsequence $a_{n_k}$ in $ A \cap B$

By the criterion above, the subsequence of $a_{n_k}$, lets call it $a_{n_{k_j}}$, converges to a point $p_A$ in $A$ and a point $p_B$ in $B$.

Since the limit of a convergent sequence is unique, $p = p_A = p_B$.
Therefore  $p \in A\cap B$ and $a_{n_{k_j}}$ converges to a point in $A\cap B$.

Let me know if/where I made a fatal mistake, or how one might approach the problem differently.

Thanks!

Comment: The subsequence tending to $p_B$ may be **different** to that tending to $p_A$.

Comment: You need to take a subsequence of the subsequence to make sure the limits are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that you have two **different** subsequences of $(a_n)$, one converging to a point in $A$, and another subsequence converging to some point in $A\cap B$. Then the "limits are unique" argument doesn't work, because you're looking at different (sub)sequences.

To fix this, start with a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ converging to some point in $A$, and then take a subsequence of this subsequence, say $(a_{n_{k_j}})$. Then your argument works.

Aside: it's simpler to use Heine-Borel to show this is true.

Comment: Another way is to first show that if a sequence $s$ in $B$ converges to $p$ then   $p\in B.$  Because $s$ has a subsequence  converging to some $q\in B,$ but $s$ is converging to $p$ so every subsequence of $s$ converges to $p,$ so $q=p$.... So a subsequence $ s$ of $(a_n)$ that converges to some $p\in A$ is also a convergent sequence in $B$, so $p\in B.$